# Wrong payload conversion Arduino

Tags: arduino, payload

Hello I'm newbie with arduino and maybe is a silly question, but I'm trying to convert `long` numbers to `byte`.

My code is:

```
float f_longitud = 179.1234567;
byte payload[4];

long longitud= f_longitud * 10000000;
SerialUSB.println(longitud);

payload[0] = (byte) ((longitud & 0xFF000000) >> 24 );
payload[1] = (byte) ((longitud & 0x00FF0000) >> 16 );
payload[2] = (byte) ((longitud & 0x0000FF00) >> 8 );
payload[3] = (byte) ((longitud & 0X000000FF));
SerialUSB.println(payload[0]);
```

The problem is that the first `println` theoretically has to show `1791234567`, because I'm just multiplying `179.1234567 x 10000000` but it shows `1791234560`. Why is this 0 appearing? Where is the 7?

The second problem is that `payload[0]` should be `6A` hex, but my `println` shows `106`. Why is not converting it correctly? Does this problem comes because of the previous error?

Below I show a scheme of what I'm doing. It's from the [this link](https://github.com/akirasan/TTN_LoRaWAN/blob/master/TTN%20-%20Optimizacion%20Payload.pdf).

[image]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that the first println theoretically has to show
>   1791234567, because I'm just multiplying 179.1234567 x 10000000 but it
>   shows 1791234560. Why is this 0 appearing? Where is the 7?

This is probably due to precision limits of `float`. Try `double` instead.

> The second problem is that payload[0] should be 6A hex, but my println
>   shows 106.

You can provide a format for [println()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/println/), like this:

```
SerialUSB.println(payload[0], HEX);
```